# Combining multiple identical SQLite queries into one

Tags: python, sqlite

I am optimizing a small app I wrote to reduce the number of database calls per request, and do not know how to structure my SQL query.

I have data something like this

```
name   stat1   stat2   stat3
john    1       2       22
john    2       4       -2
richard 3       4       0
john    0       3       1
jacob   12      9       -20
```

My current statement is something along the lines of:

```
userNames = execute("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM ___")
for user in userNames:
    var userdata = "SELECT avg(stat1), avg(stat2), avg(stat3) FROM ___ WHERE name == '"+str(user)
```

Now this understandably is not good. It makes 20 calls (thankfully my users table is low right now), but it scales very poorly. (each db call takes .050s)

A friend suggested something along the lines of:

```
"SELECT avg(stat1),avg(stat2),avg(stat3) from ___ where name in " userNames
```

But this only returns one row, where I need len(userNames) # of rows.

Is this a good case to use Join? (I am a sql noob).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't about Python or joins.

What you need here is aggregation. You want to calculate the average values for each distinct name, and you do that in SQL via `GROUP BY`. So:

```
SELECT name, avg(stat1), avg(stat2), avg(stat3) FROM ____ GROUP BY name;
```

output (in sqlite):

```
jacob|12.0|9.0|-20.0
john|1.0|3.0|7.0
richard|3.0|4.0|0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Added an additional constraint and now it works beautifully.

`SELECT name, avg(stat1)... FROM ___ WHERE name in (....) GROUP BY name`